# Запятые непосредственно вокруг "И". Возможно?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, и

Например, если впереди вводная конструкция, а сзади запятая, разделяющая части сложного предложения:

> Проявилась эксцентричная зависимость, и, по видимому, случай этот окажется уникальным.

Comment: Пардон, а "эксцентричная зависимость" -- это что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, конечно, такое возможно.
В Вашем предложении пунктуационно все верно, кроме [**по-видимому**](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2722).
(**Через дефис** пишутся наречия с приставкой ***по-***, образованные от полных форм прилагательных и от местоимений и оканчивающиеся на ***-ому***/-ему, -ки, -ьи:
**по-видимому**; по-пустому; работать по-новому... (п. 9)).

И в формулировке неточность: **первая** запятая разделяет части сложного предложения, а вторая — перед вводным словом.

Вот интересное предложение, в котором есть пунктуационные особенности, связанные с вводными словами.
*Отлучение от церкви было действительно суровым наказанием, применявшимся в особых случаях; **однако** западноевропейские правители подвергались ему довольно часто, **и, по крайней мере** если говорить о нормандцах, оно, **по-видимому**, не слишком влияло на их политику; обычно им удавалось добиться того, что отлучение вскоре снимали.*
Д. Норвич. Нормандцы в Сицилии. Второе нормандское завоевание. 1016-1130

Answer (score 2):

> Возможно?

Да. Вы правильно рассудили. Только "по-видимому" пишется через дефис.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, вопрос вызван тем, что запятая после "и" противоречит интонации (здесь *невозможна* речевая пауза). Дело в том, что пунктуация в русском языке основывается *преимущественно* на грамматическом разборе предложения, поэтому запятые, возникающие при двустороннем выделении (=обособлении) оборотов, не могут исключаться в интересах правильной интонации. Здесь требует обособления вводное слово "**по-видимому**" - запятая после "и" возникает от этого. Запятая же *перед* "и" ставится для отделения второго предложения, имеющего *свои* подлежащее и сказуемое.

Answer (score 1):

**Проявилась эксцентричная зависимость, и, по-видимому, случай этот окажется уникальным.**

1) Да, **эксцентричное предложение**, хотя запятые расставлены верно.

а) **Эксцентричная зависимость** ― это что? Такой **термин** существует в медицине? Или это **странная** (необычная) зависимость от чего-либо? А может быть, это **склонность** к эксцентричному поведению?

б) **Случай окажется уникальным**... причем *по-видимому, скорее всего, почти наверняка*. А когда он окажется и как понять, что уже оказался.

в) Вариант редактирования: ...**и, возможно, случай этот может оказаться уникальным.**

ЭКСЦЕНТРИЧНЫЙ,  Книжн. 1. Необычный, странный, вызывающе оригинальный. Э-ая мода. Э. наряд. Э-ое поведение. Э-ые манеры. Э. рисунок. 2. Крайне своеобразный, склонный к причудам, странным поступкам. Э. молодой человек. Э-ая натура. Э. характер.

2) Постановка запятых в данном предложении независимая и соответствует **грамматическому принципу.** Вводное слово обособляется с двух сторон, однако в сложных конструкциях **интонационно оно не выделяется.**

Прочтение предложения:

Проявилась эксцентричная завИсимость, **(пауза, повышение тона)** и, по-видимому, случай этот **(произносительная пауза**) окажется уникАльным (**понижение тона в конце предложения**).

Comment: Вот если эксцентричным может быть не только человек, его поведение и т. п., а рисунок (неодушевлённое), предложение вот у вас, то почему бы не описывать так странные, редкие, выходящие из ряда вон математические показатели? В данном случае под зависимость имеется в виду число от 0 до 1. Например, среди многочисленных опытов (пускай цель которых будет определить причины рака) за 50 лет образовался многотысячный рад из показателей до 0,03. И тут бац, 0,67 – эксцентричный показатель, сенсационно, невероятно на фоне остальных (да и не только на фоне).

Comment: Я употребила выражение  "эксцентричное предложение"  в ироническом смысле. Для широкой аудитории всё эксцентричное близко по значению к вызывающему. Это обычно люди  неуравновешенные, странные (эзотерики сказали бы, что у них смещенный центр сборки); это их поведение, поступки, одежда, и т.д. Если эксцентричная зависимость -  общепринятая терминология в научной среде, то нет вопросов, если это научно-популярный текст, то Вас могут не понять или определить выражение как стилистически неточное. Я бы использовала такие синонимы, как  "совершенно необычный, выходящий за пределы обычного".